# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in HTML

Tags: html

I have been researching and reading other questions about my error that I am receiving. I have defined the the variable and it matches the name syntax but I am still getting the error from this line: 
name2 = document.madLibForm.name2.value;

That the value is not defined. This is my very first html program so I am not to familiar on how to debug outside of looking into chrome to see where the error lies. Below is my code. I have everything else working but this. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- 
strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Mad Lib </title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function generateMadLib() {
//Declaring and Initializing variables
var action1 = "";
var action2 = "";
var name ="";
var name2 ="";
var character1 = "";
var character2 = "";
var age ="";
var theSelect;
var choice = 0;
var theOption;
var story = "";

/*
  Retrieving Name
    document.madLibForm.txtName 
        -- madLibForm matches the name of the <form> element.
        -- txtName matches the name of the <input> element.     
*/  
name = document.madLibForm.txtName.value;
name2 = document.madLibForm.name2.value;

//Gathering Action1 Variables
if (document.madLibForm.chkRunning.checked == true) {
action1 = "Running, ";
 } //end if
if (document.madLibForm.chkSleeping.checked == true) {
action1 += "Sleeping, ";
} //end if
if (document.madLibForm.chkGrowling.checked == true) {
action1 += "Growling, ";
} //end if
if (document.madLibForm.chkNipping.checked == true) {
action1 += "Nipping, ";
 } //end if

//Getting Age
if (document.madLibForm.age[0].checked == true) {
age = document.madLibForm.age[0].value;
} else {
  age = document.madLibForm.age[1].value;
} //end if

//Retrieving Character 1
theSelect = document.madLibForm.character1;
choice = theSelect.selectedIndex;
theOption = theSelect.options[choice];
character1 = theOption.value;

//Retrieving Character 2
theSelect = document.madLibForm.character2;
choice = theSelect.selectedIndex;
theOption = theSelect.options[choice];
character2 = theOption.value;

//Getting action 2
if (document.madLibForm.action2[0].checked == true) {
action2 = document.madLibForm.action2[0].value;
} else {
  action2 = document.madLibForm.action2[1].value;
} //end if


//Story
story = "Today our story is about a day in the life of " + name + ". This " + age +
 " dog belongs to " + name2 + ". " + name + " has spent their day " + action1 +
 ".  This doggy knows no bounds when it comes to living his life. Today " + name +
  " is sitting out on the front porch with " + name2 + " when all of a sudden " + character1 + " and 
 " + character2 +
 " walk past their home. " + character2 + " is " + action2 + " while " + character1 + " is looking 
 over them." + name +
 " jumps out of " + name2 + " arms and tries to help " + character2 + " but, " + character1 +
 " tries to stop him. Eventually,  " + name2 +" arrives and is able to control " + name +
 " and apologies to everyone for his overly helpful attitude. ";
  document.madLibForm.story.value = story;
  } 
  </script>
  </head>

 <h1>Mad Lib</h1>

 This is a "mad-lib" simulation page.  By selecting the options and inputing information in the 
 textboxes in the form below and then clicking on "Tell Me the Story", you will see a creative story 
 in the textarea.

 <form name = "madLibForm">
 <h3>Type a name for your dog:</h3>
 <input type = "text" name = "txtName" value = "">
 <P>

 <h3>Choose a verb:</h3>
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "chkRunning" value = "running">Running<br>
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "chkSleeping" value = "sleeping">Sleeping<br>
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "chkGrowling" value = "growling">Growling<br>
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "chkNipping" value = "nipping">Nipping<br>

<h3>Pick if this is an adult or puppy</h3>
 <input type = "radio" name = "age" value = "puppy">Puppy<br>
 <input type = "radio" name = "age" value = "adult">Adult<br>
 <P>

<h3>Choose a character</h3>
<select name = "character1">
<option value = ""></option>
<option value = "Police Officer">Police Officer</option>
<option value = "Mailman">MailMan</option>
<option value = "Hobo">Hobo</option>
</select>
<p>

<h3>Choose another character but not the same one from before</h3>
<select name = "character2">
<option value = ""></option>
<option value = "Police Office">Police Officer</option>
<option value = "Mailman">Mailman</option>
<option value = "Hobo">Hobo</option>
</select>
<p>

<h3>Pick an adjective</h3>
<input type = "radio" name = "action2" value = "Running">Running<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "action2" value = "Screaming">Screaming<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "action2" value = "Crying">Crying<br>
<P>

<h3>Type in your name:</h3>
<input type = "text" name2 = "txtname2" value = "">
<P>

<input type = "button" value = "Tell Me the Story" onClick = "generateMadLib()">
<input type="reset">
<p>

<h3>Here is the story:</h3>
<textarea name= "story" rows="20" cols="80" wrap>
</textarea>
<p/>
<a href="index.html">Back to Main Page</a>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: var `madLibForm` is not set

Comment: @I'mLimit It's defined implicitly.

Comment: This line is wrong: `<input type = "text" name2 = "txtname2" value = "">`. You have no form field with the name attribute set to `name2`.

Comment: For future reference: there's no such thing as an HTML program. Your programming is done in JavaScript in this case.

Comment: ok l got it as @RobbyCornelissen comment you use `<input type = "text" name2 = "txtname2" value = "">`
need to set to
`<input type = "text" name = "name2" value = "">`

Comment: Thanks guys! That worked. For learning off the web and without a teacher I say HTML is not that bad. I was learning on the fly to try and help someone troubleshoot the issue at hand. I was trying to use my logic from debugging javascript, c++, and SQL